# What happens to ASP.Net SignalR messages that are sent to a page which is in the middle of a PostBack?

Tags: asp.net, signalr

I have an ASP.Net application that uses SignalR to communicate between pages.
What happens to a SignalR message that gets sent to a target page that is in the middle of a PostBack?
SignalR isn't guaranteed delivery, so does that message get lost?
With each PostBack, doesn't the page get a new SignalR connection?

Comment: What do you mean "communicate between pages"? Do you mean from user to user or if the user has multiple pages open? Or it just loads whenever a user loads a page?

Answer (score 0):

It depends is on the design. As you stated, it's not guaranteed messaging, so it is lost to the ether.

If you stored your messages, say in a database, and had a "mark as read" flag on them when they are delivered to the recipient, then they would not get lost. But if you did not store them, they would likely never be delivered because after the POST you would have a new connectionID and the server may not know if it's intended for you.

The real question here, IMHO, is why are you using POST? The purpose behind SignalR is to NOT refresh, POST, GET, Ajax, etc. SignalR provides the ability to communicate back to the server and do something (commit to a database, perform a query, send a message to another client, and so on).

I've built a few robust systems now sending simple text, data points, and small/large JSON data for updating HTML, CSS, dashboards, charts and tables without using any other method to communicate back to the server and/or another client.

Maybe check out a few videos from [channel9.msdn.com](http://channel9.msdn.com) such as:
https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/dotnetConf/2014/SignalR

It's older but goes nicely enough into the intentions of the product straight from one of the lead developers.

Comment: Sorry, but you seem to miss the point of the question. When users use a web application, they still use GET when navigating to another page, still use POST to submit forms and still may use AJAX to update data in a grid. You don't want to create a SPA that gets all its data from SignalR. The question is simple: if a SignalR message is "in flight" (i.e. not received on the JS side yet), and the user refreshes the page, what happens to the message? The answer to that is not "The purpose behind SignalR is to NOT refresh ...".

Comment: I don't believe I did miss the point of the question and answered that first thing. It depends on how you designed it. That was my answer to his question. The rest was "IMHO" as shown. Not going to get into a comment debate about usage, I referred him to resources to make his own decision and gain additional understanding from a lead developer. My experience is that I can use it to create an SPA with only SignalR for sending/receiving data.

Comment: Yes, you can, but the OP didn't, given the need for their users to perform a POST. So you can argue _"I don't know the answer to your question, but I would design your entire application differently"_ (and still not catch missed messages when the user presses F5 or navigates away for whatever reason), but that would be a lousy answer now wouldn't it?